# Identifying Entities and Value Objects in Facebook domain model

Tags: c#, java, facebook, domain-driven-design

If I were building a social network where **Users** can just share **Posts**, I would have modeled User as **entity** while Posts as a collection of **value objects**.

However, in Facebook Posts can be liked by other Users. Posts can have **Comments**. Comments can also be liked by other Users.

I have always read that an Entity has an identity that we care about, but a Value object doesn't.

Introducing the concept of comments and likes somewhat elevated the importance of a Post. Now I need to identify which Comment relates to which Post. Similarly I need to identify which Post or Comment is liked by which User.

If I have 2 Posts with the exact wording "Some dummy post goes here"
, but the 1st is liked by User1 and User2 while the 2nd is like by User3 and User4 then I should conclude that these are different posts. However, it would have been easier to just compare the identities of the posts.

**TL;DR**

**Does introducing a relation to a Value Object promote it to an Entity?**

Answer (score 1):

Let's clear up things:

- **Entities** always have an Id, because you want to identify them regardless of their other values.
- **Value objects** (VO) encapsulate a value and are interchangeable, you don't care about the object, you only care about the value. The reason you're using a VO instead of just the value (assuming it's not a composite) is that a VO is always in valid state and 'guarantees' that you're working with a valid value.

There's **no *promotion*** from a VO to an Entity, they should model the right domain concept from the beginning.

In your scenario, the Posts, Comments and Users are always entities. Posts don't have comments, [they are associated with comments](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/10/18/Modelling-Aggregate-Roots-Relationships.aspx). **Like** is a use case of User, Post and Comment.

You'll have a LikesTracker or similar which will associate the likes of user with a post or comment.

I disagree with the structure suggested by @Alexey Raga, because it's the wrong (CRUD) modelling. First of all, User and Post are Aggregate Roots, not Aggregates (which signifies a group of context related concepts). I don't understand why Like should be a VO, but regardless, collections of Like and Comments are not part of the definition of the Post concept and they don't belong there.

That structure makes sense for a read (view) model, but NOT for the domain model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in DDD but...
Entities are objects that are returned by repositories. To access a value-object you need to pull an entity from repository and then get the value-object from the entity.

So I think you should ask yourself a question: What objects from database I want to get directly to populate the view?
IMO you will need to get User from db, for example to display users profile, change password etc. So User might be your entity. As for the Posts it **depends**. If you are planning just to display the list of user posts, Post could be a value-object. But if you are planning to implement a posts search (for example by date range) then Post should be your entity.

To summarize. It all depends on what you are trying to achive.

Answer (score 0):

I think making Post a Value Object is rather unwise.
Looking at the domain and at the language around this domain we can see that Post is probably an entity (an aggregate) itself. As you mentioned, the domain "talks" in terms of posts.

Posts also provide some *behaviors* and can be acted on. For example, you may want to have a link to a particular post, or to share a particular post, etc.

Another (technical) reason not to make Post a Value Object is that you probably don't want to load a User aggregate with all the posts when you want to display just a particular one.

So Post can be modeled as an aggregate, which can have some AuthorId, etc.

Likes, however, can be treated as Value Objects. So Post and Comment can have a collection of Likes.

As for comments, I would probably model them as Entities within the Post aggregate. Remember, entities have IDs *in scope of their aggregate instances*, so each Post can have Comment#1, Comment#2, etc. 
And entities may have their own structure and behaviors (for example, their own collections of Likes).

Another thing to consider is that an Aggregate is a Transactional Boundary. There is no need to wrap User and Post in the same transaction, their behaviors are totally independent, therefore User and Post are different Aggregates.

So I would probably start with the following structure:

- User (Aggregate)
- Post (Aggregate)

  - Collection[Like] (each Like is a Value Object)
  - Collection[Comment] (each Comment is an Entity)

    - Each Comment has a Collection[Like]

Hope it helps.